# Customize the Size of HTML 5 audio Control

Tags: html, html5-audio

How do I customize the size of audio control ?
Need to minimize the PLAY button but unable to do so.

Comment: This is not a 'write-my-code' site. Show us what you tried and where exactly your problem lies.

Comment: I tried using anchor tag and played the audio player in the back-end.That served my purpose.